# Zerofill in Workflows

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, sharepoint-designer

I'm trying to create a searchable ID for a list using Workflows. I do it by setting a field to ARN[ID] (which give me something like ARN1) but I want to zerofill it so it looks like ARN001. How can I do this using workflows? I can't find anything about it.

I'm attaching an image below to show how I've done the flow.

[image: Image of my workflow]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make a string which is the last X characters of X zeroes + ID (Despite the text in the picture below the action is named `Extract Substring from End of String`)
2. Prefix that string with your prefix
3. Assign that string to your field

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But I don't have the "Copy X characters". The only thing I find when I search for "copy" is "Copy List Item".

I'm running Foundation, might this be the problem?

Comment: It's called `Extract Substring from End of String`